# Can web workers be restarted by the brower at any time?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I've read in many places (including here, in Stack Overflow) that web workers can be killed and restarted by the browser at any time. Well, probably "at any time" means "as long as they are doing something", but the thing is that they can be killed and restarted by the browser without prior warning, losing any data stored in `globalThis`.

But for the life of me I cannot find that in the specification, and it worries me because I'm actually using a Web Worker whose proper functioning relies in keeping some info data in a global variable to keep minimal state between calls of the message handling function.

This web worker works like a charm, and state is kept unless of course the page is refreshed, but I'm afraid that the app can fail if the browser decides to restart the web worker, and for sure it will if that happens.

I've googled about this, specially looking for examples and alternatives for rewriting my web worker without the need for that global state, but I haven't found anything relevant.

Can anyone point me to some official information about this?

Comment: Not a direct answer per se, but keeping important state in memory (without a CRC check) is always a bad idea. Granted memory checking is typically done by the operating system or other lower level software, but I think the same idea follows in your case. In short: I think I'd back up that state into local storage or similar.
If for nothing, you could at least tell later if the memory state does not match anymore.

Comment: @Christian, memory integrity here is not the issue at all. I don't do CRC checks for the variables in my programs, ever, so why should do it here? My problem is not about memory integrity but to the fact that the web worker may be restarted, which is something I would not expect from common JavaScript code, but well, workers are different. Thanks anyway!

Comment: To be clear, I didn't mean memory checks in case of corruption (although it does make sense in long-running processes...like workers), but rather in case of restarts etc. This is not an unusual thing to do. If you're familiar with PHP, `__sleep` and `__wakeup` serve a similar purpose. Anyway, just something to think over. I don't want to get any further off topic.

Comment: That'd be great if you could link to these claims made on SO, so we can see if indeed that's what they were saying (and thus were wrong), and might need edit or if that's how you read it (thus they were unclear and might need edit).

Comment: @Kaiido, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38976243/4994781 (see the last sentence). And after reading your answer, the problem was misunderstanding on my part. Yes, a web worker can be killed silently, that's entirely true, BUT that does not mean "arbitrarily" or "it will be killed and restarted".  No edit needed, I'm the one entirely to blame here.  For the other references I would have to find them amongst my browsing history of three days, and they were outside of SO. From SO I only have the one I've sent you linked. I found another one but I can't find it again, sorry.

Comment: No problem, I understand. And indeed, what they say there is "In this very particular case of a buggy browser..." But that's what it is (was?): a browser bug. This might happen, but if it does you need to let the browser vendor know so they can fix it.

Comment: What I interpreted, @Kaiido, was that the particular problem there was caused by a browser bug, BUT that IN GENERAL browsers could kill and restart web workers arbitrarily. And I may finally rewrite my web worker so a different instance is spawned for each task, eliminating the need for the worker's state, but anyway I wanted to know for future reference. Thanks a lot for your invaluable help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've read in many places (including here, in Stack Overflow) that web workers can be killed **and restarted** by the browser at any time.

Nope, they won't ever restart your (dedicated) Worker in any way.

The browser can kill a Worker if

- The main navigable (a.k.a "page") is killed.
- The [`Worker#terminate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate) method has been called.
- The [`DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope#close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope/close) method has been called, and the current task is completed.
- The Worker [becomes "orphan"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model:permissible-worker). This may happen when it stops being a ["protected worker"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#protected-worker), i.e.

  - when the Worker is a sub-Worker (itself created from a Worker) and its owner has been killed,
  - or when it has no scheduled tasks, no ongoing network request or database transaction, and no `MessagePort` or inner `Worker` objects susceptible of receiving messages from the outside.

So as long as you keep a reference to your `Worker` object in your main thread, and don't call yourself one of the closing methods, there is no way the Worker can be killed by the browser.

---

*Note: The rules for SharedWorkers, ServiceWorkers, and other Worklets are all different, this answer treats only Dedicated Workers, created from `new Worker()`.*

Comment: thanks a LOT for your highly detailed answer and for pointing me to the parts of the standard I was misreading (or missing entirely) and explaining all bits to me. All this means I can keep some sort of minimal state within the worker instead of having to pass around potentially huge Transferable Objects or launch separate workers per operation, which would not be the end of the world but would complicate things anyway.